# is this the way of using goslate

Tags: python, goslate

iam trying to make a translator using goslate but it shows many errors what to do? the following is my code

```
 import goslate

text = "Hello world"
gs = goslate.Goslate()
translated = gs.translate(text,'fr')
print(translated)
```

the errors are as follows:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/rijilvarghese/Documents/translator.py", line 5, in <module>
   translated = gs.translate(text,'fr')
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/goslate.py", line 409, in translate
return _unwrapper_single_element(self._translate_single_text(text, target_language, source_language))
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/goslate.py", line 334, in _translate_single_text
results = list(self._execute(make_task(i) for i in split_text(text)))
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/goslate.py", line 203, in _execute
yield each()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/goslate.py", line 332, in <lambda>
return lambda: self._basic_translate(text, target_language, source_lauguage)[0]
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/goslate.py", line 251, in _basic_translate
response_content = self._open_url(url)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/goslate.py", line 191, in _open_url
raise e
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/goslate.py", line 181, in _open_url
response = self._opener.open(request, timeout=self._TIMEOUT)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
response = meth(req, response)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
       urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

i have tried so many ways but that doesn't work please help me for my project

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems `goslate` is deprecated - the mechanism it was using is no longer viable, because Google messed with their API in such a way that `goslate` can  no longer use it. [See also the top of the pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/) or [the project's repo](https://bitbucket.org/zhuoqiang/goslate/src/default/). You may need to look for a different tool to do your translation for you - after a cursory search, [this page](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/translate/) seems to list a few alternatives.

Comment: but when i tried it for first time that worked